# reading file using BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and I was reading the a file using the **BufferedInputStream()**. Can someone tell me why I can't read my file? If I print obj.read(), it returns -1 everytime. Instead it should return the unicode value of every character that the stream is reading.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream obj = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
            BufferedInputStream obj2= new BufferedInputStream(obj);
            while(obj2.read()!=-1)
            {
                System.out.print((char) obj2.read());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("program executed");

    }
}
```

But after introducing a local variable the code works, why???

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream obj = new FileInputStream("riten.txt");
            BufferedInputStream obj2= new BufferedInputStream(obj);
            int a;
            while((a=obj2.read())!=-1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)a);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("program executed");

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because your program won't compile. You have a syntax error on line N - your compiler will tell you the line number, for sure.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Sorry for the mistake, I fixed it, I am still not getting the output.

Comment: Inside the loop, I am type casting the unicode value to char to get the output

Comment: In your first example the first thing you do is read from the "buffered stream", that means it reads a lot of bytes as a buffer. Then you call read from the 'FileInputStream' but it has already been consumed because the BufferedInputStream read the whole file. **Don't read from the same stream with different streams!**

Comment: @matt Thanks for your help, mate! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from your BufferedInputStream and not from the FileInputStream. You are mixing things here.

But in addition to your code you need to properly handle streams, i.e. when you open a file you need to close those afterwards.

A fix of your code. I added a local variable to store the read character and then cast it to a character.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream obj = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
        BufferedInputStream obj2= new BufferedInputStream(obj);
        int c;
        while((c = obj2.read())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("program executed");

}
```

Comment: Why do I need to introduce a local variable?

Comment: Also why are you type casting it to char if it returns  a byte :(

Comment: Once a value is read from the stream the pointer moves on. A subsequent call to read() would simply return the next value. So if you don't store it to a variable for printing in your case it is lost.

Comment: @RitenBhagra casting to `char` causes [print(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char)) to be called instead of [print(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(int))

Comment: @spehler62 Thank you so much. You're a life saviour.

Comment: The method read() returns an int. If you want the ASCII you can use byte but if you want the character you need to cast to char.